# Does the Google calendars API allow you to add an event as an iCalendar/vcard (string)?

Tags: php, api, zend-framework

I want to be able to add calendar events to different calendar providers as easily as possible. So that i don't have to write specific api code each time, i was hoping that i could perhaps use an iCalendar creator class in php to create an event in a standard format and then send that raw information to the provider (Google at first), without having to fill in all the individual api specific fields for the event (like with the Zend Google calendars framework). Can Google Calendars accept a vcard/icalendar string as raw input, or can i send it via a post method in the Zend Google Calendars library?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can import into google calendar events via CSV files from the settings page. The only limitation to the csv file is that you can not import periodic events. For this you need to create a file of events that meets the specifications icalendar